# Sidekiq job keeps running in Rails, even though it isn't in the codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I used to have a job called `DeleteYearOldApplicationsJob`, we removed the job but it still runs in Sidekiq even though I have cleared the queues. There isn't reference to this job in the code any longer.

I know it runs because I get reports in my application monitor that says `NameError: uninitialized constant DeleteYearOldApplicationsJob` in `sidekiq#DeleteYearOldApplicationsJob`.

I ran this in the console to clear the jobs

```
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset
Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.clear
```

This is an older project, Rails 4.2.8 and Sidekiq 5.0.5.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Check any scheduled jobs from the Sidekiq UI